# How to get Total in subform Access Datasheet View

Tags: ms-access, vba, subform

Currently I'm working on subform in Access. I need to get the total hours spend. I have tried using =SUM([Hours]) but still not getting the total hours in Datasheet View.

The output the expected is as below:-

- Application      Hours
- A              2
- B              2
- C              2
- D              2

  Total             8

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to show the total at the bottom of the datasheet itself. In this case, the functionality you want is built in. In the home tab of the ribbon, there is a button labeled "Totals" which displays a totals bar beneath the new record at the very bottom of your datasheet in datasheet view.